# Zero divisor in ring without unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

Let $R$ be a commutative ring **without unity** and $n \in R\setminus\{0\}$. Prove that $n\mid n$ implies that $n$ is a zero divisor.

Comment: Is this a commutative ring?

Comment: Yes, it is. I forget to mention that.

Comment: We can prove it only for commutative ring.
For the not commutative ring:

Let n = k*n
n*n = k*n*n
n*n = n*k*n
0 = (k*n - n*k)*n
=> n is the zero divisor or k*n = n*k and we can go to subring, created by n and k

Comment: Can we extend R to a ring with unity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume that $n=nk$ for some $k\in R$. Because $R$ has no unity, there exists an element $r\in R$ such that $kr\neq r$. In other words $kr-r\neq0$.

But by standard applications of rng axioms
$$
n(kr-r)=n(kr)-nr=(nk)r-nr=nr-nr=0.
$$
Therefore $n$ is a zero-divisor.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jyrki Lahtonen. You saw the trick!

Comment: For an example of a rng where this can happen consider the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\Bbb{Z}$. In other words
$$R=\{(n_1,n_2,\ldots)\mid n_i\in\Bbb{Z}\ \text{such that $n_i\neq0$ for only finitely many $i$}\}.$$ This is a rng with componentwise operations. Clearly $n=(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ is divisible by itself. And also a zero divisor.

Comment: Where is commutativity used?

Comment: @Serge I use commutativity in concluding that there exists an $r$ such that $kr\neq r$ specifically. Otherwise I would need to worry about the possibility that $k$ might be a one-sided unity but not a two-sided one. That is, I avoid the headache possibility  that $kr=r$ for all $r$, but may be $rk\neq r$ for some $r$, when we still could not conclude that $k$ is a multiplicative neutral element. My exposure to rngs is kinda lacking, so I can't tell right away, whether it is possible that a rng could have a one-sided identity :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Moreover, if $R$ is not commutative, $n\mid n$ is not well defined: one should distinguishing between left divisor and right divisor.